# 1second down counter with initial value verilog code

Tags: verilog, counter

I want to write the code of  1-second  down counter that get the initial value from outside and count it down till 0. but there is a problem. How can I get the initial value. i tried some ways but ....
here is the code:

```
module second_counter (        input clk,
                        input top_num,
                        output reg [3:0] sec_num
                        );

parameter clk_frequency = 25;
reg [31:0]cnt;
wire [3:0]sec;

/// how can get the top_num and count it down.

assign sec=top_num;


always @(posedge clk)
begin
if (cnt==clk_frequency)
    begin
        sec <= sec -1;
        cnt<=0;
    end
else
cnt <=cnt+1;
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you basically need is a **reset** signal. Just like clock, reset is to be added in the sensitivity list.

After instantiation of module, you must apply a reset signal to initialize all the internal variables and registers of design.

Following code gives you initial value of `cnt` by reset application. This is an **active low** reset.

```
module second_counter ( input clk, input reset, input top_num, output reg [3:0] sec_num ); 
parameter clk_frequency = 25;
reg [31:0]cnt; 
// wire [3:0]sec; 
reg [3:0] sec;
/// 
// assign sec=top_num; 
always @(posedge clk, negedge reset) 
begin 
if(!reset)
begin
    cnt<=0;  // initialize all internal variables and registers
    sec<=0;
end 
else
begin
    if(sec == 0) // latch input when previous count is completed
        sec<=top_num;
    if (cnt==clk_frequency) 
    begin 
        sec <= sec -1; 
        cnt<=0; 
    end 
    else 
        cnt <=cnt+1; 
end
end
```

Note that this is an **asynchronous** reset, means it does not depend on clocking signal. **Synchronous** reset is the one which only affects the registers at the clock pulse.

**Edit**:

Regarding to `sec`, I have modified the code. Now the design latches the inputs for one clock cycle and counts down to zero. Once the counter reaches zero, it again latches the input to re-count to zero.

Note that you cannot do like latching `top_num` at every clock and counting through zero (since top_num can change at every pulse). For latching at every clock pulse, you need more complex logic implementation.

Comment: thanks i want use this code for real time changing . i wnt to apply this in cmplicated code and i dont want reset .  but cnt is not important for me in this case. my question is that how can i connect  top_num to sec in order to count down for example my code operation is like; get the top_num=5 and the output show me 5--4--3--2--1--0 .

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly. If top_num=5, the counter will now count down to 0. Then again latch value of top_num(let's say 7) and count down to 0.

Comment: And ya, top_num must be a 4 bit wide input.

Comment: thanks very much , I didnt want the reset but I learned new technique in coding.